# Raspberry Pi A+ is saying WiFi is connected when it isn't

Tags: wifi, raspbian-wheezy, pi-a+

I have had a hard time with this Pi, finding the drivers was not a easy task, and now am experiencing a new issue.

My WiFi dongle is flashing green (which is a good sign). In the GUI WiFi setup it's saying I am connected, but problem is I don't have a IP address nor am I able to ping or connect to the internet.

Interfaces File

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
        ssid="Claro"
        psk="password12"
        proto=RSN
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        group=CCMP TKIP
}
```

GNU nano 2.2.6         File: /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

I am running Raspbian Wheezy.

Comment: Depending on the OS release the above won't work (unless you have made other changes). See http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697 I haven't the faintest idea what "its saying i am connected in the GUI wifi setup only problem is I don't have a IP address" actually means.

Comment: so when i open the graphical interface on the desktop and open the wifi set-up I look and it says I am connected , it goes through the handshake etc. and claims i am connected to my network, but when i try to go to google for an example it will not work and unable to obtain IP, I will check the link out, thanks

Comment: unfortunately this did nothing... took me back to my starting point essentially. restored it to my last settings as it seemed to be progress in comparison of sitting doing nothing...Really wish there was a official page dedicated to this stuff

Comment: what does `ifconfig` show? There are official pages, but they all assume you are using the latest version and not using out of date configuration files. Is this a new installation? Why are you trying to use Wheezy - which is not supported, or even available any more?

Comment: pi@raspberrypi ~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 3.18.7+ #755 PREEMPT Thu Feb 12 17:14:31 GMT 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ifconfig
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:b5:c2:05:ff:16  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

pi@raspberrypi ~ $

Comment: I downloaded the NOOBS v1.4 and installed raspian [recommended ]

Comment: Essentially I need to wipe my SD and download this?https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/

Comment: The current NOOBS is 1.7 so this must be very old. IMO NOOBS does not make things any easier, but either way install a current version of Raspbian.

Comment: WELL thank you so much, so much stress gone, worked out of the box i feel like kicking myself for being so numb and using a old version on my sd card that i downloaded earlier.... all i did was boot it , signed in and woola connected prompt for password (wifi) connected

Comment: version is nice cause its out of the box but, i notice its super slow, everytime i access the terminal it freezes up on me

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this in your `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp

wpa-ssid "Claro"
wpa-psk "password12"
```

Comment: If you get an error, change your `wpa_supplicant.conf` back to default.

Comment: I have had issues with wheezy and wifi in the past, jessie fixed this for me. wpa supplicant didn't do the trick for me, sot his answer might be useful to try out.

Comment: Hey guys, I actually changes the OS over to Jessie and it works great just very slow when accessing the terminal unfortunately but may be voltage issues

Answer (score 0):

Changed to Jessie worked out of the box. Had issue with voltage because my usb port was hogging energy, as well as using a host-dependendent USB hub.. solution was to use independent USB hub or just use SSH, works amazing.